# Is Default Package included in the Package Level Access?

Tags: java

I would like to know how the default package is defined in Java.I know how public and private access is defined but I don't know whether there is any default package access that is defined in package level access in java.

The code I tried to execute is:

```
  class A
  {
    public static void value()
    {
    int a;
    a=5;
    }
    public static void main()
    {
    value();
    }
  }
  class B
  {
    public void greet()
    {
    System.out.println("Value of a is"+a);
    }
  }
```

The error I got is:

```
D:\Downloads\pro>javac A.java
A.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("Value of a is"+a);
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable a
  location: class B
1 error
```

*Since both classes belong to the same default package shouldn't class B access class A's members(a)?*

I'm asking this question because when I compile java file containing two classes since no modifier is given for classes,java compiler would give package level access as the default access modifier for the classes.Since no package is defined,java compiler would use the default package but I couldn't get whether the default package is included in package level access in java.Could anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I got how we could access an variable in another class without creating an object provided both classes rest in the same package.Just make the variable **static**.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
  class A
  {
  static int a=5;
    public void turn()
    {
    System.out.println("value of a is"+a);
    }
  }
  class B
  {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    int b;
    b=A.a;
    System.out.println("value of a is"+b);
    }
  }
```

*This shows that classes residing in the **same package** can access each other's members provided it is static even though it is not public because **default package access** comes to play.*

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a variable inside the static function `value` and not visible outside of that function at all. Doesn't have to do with access specifiers.

Comment: Or to use standard Java terminology, `a` is a local variable of a method and not a field of a class.

Comment: @SebastianRedl:Couldn't a static member access it's public static members from other classes without creating an object of another class to access it.Is this possible for static members only or can this be extended to non-static members?

Comment: @justin I'm afraid your first sentence does not make sense. A static member doesn't have "it's public static members from other classes".

Comment: @SebastianRedl:Sorry.I meant to say that can an static member variable(public) in a class(say Class A) can be accessed in another class(Class B) without creating the object of Class A.Whether this could be defined for _non-static_ members too?

Comment: @justin What would that mean for non-static members though? Non-static members don't **exist** without an instance of the class.

Comment: @SebastianRedl:Yeah that's true.Does that mean _static_ members could do that as said in the previous comment?

Answer (score 1):

The **default package** is the package without a name, all classes without a package declaration at the top of the file fall into it.

It is subject to all normal rules of packages except that you can't reference classes of it from a class inside a package.

For example I have 2 java files:

```
public class A{
    public static void foo(){System.out.println("fooCalled");}
}
```

and

```
package com.example;

public class B{
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        A.foo();//won't compile
    }

}
```

Then `B` (or in the qualified form `com.example.B`) can never call the foo of A without `reflection` magic.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has nothing to do with `access specifiers`, as you have declared your variable `int a` inside a method.

Thus it becomes just a `local variable`. You cannot even use it outside this method in the same class.

If we talk specifically about access specifiers then we can have `default` access specifier in Java which has scope up to the same package only.

```
package com;
class A{
    int a; // this is an instance variable
    static int b; //this is a class variable
}

package com;
class B{
    //can use a variable here
    // To use a here, we need new A().a;
    // To use b here, we can do,  A.b
}

package hello;
class C{
    //can't use a variable here
}
```

**Edit**

Suppose we create a file with name `MyProgram.java` on `Desktop`. Below is the code of this file,

```
class First{
    int a; // a is an instance variable
    static int b;  // b is a static (class) variable

    void display(){
        int c; // c is a local variable
    }
}

class Second{
    public static void mian(){
        First obj = new First();
        obj.a = 10;  // to access instance variable we need object of the class
        obj.b = 20;  // class variable can also be accessed using the object

        // First.a = 10;  //It won't work as a is instance variable and can be accessed by object only

        // First.b = 20;  // We can also access static variables by class name directly without using any object

        // obj.c = 30;  // It won't work. As c is a local variable of method display and can be used only inside that method.

        // First.c = 30;  //It also won't work as c can only be used inside the method where it is declared.
    }
}
```

Comment: :Is there any way to access a member of class B(second class) from class A(first) without creating an object of class A?

Comment: @justin See instance methods are meant to be accessed by instance (object) of the class. You can't access an instance variable outside that class without the object. However you can create the static variables in that class, and use them directly by class name without creating an object.

Comment: :Thanks.Could you show me an example without using packages because I'm really stuck at _default_ packages.

Comment: @justin Just remove the first line `package com;` from the above program and it will be without packages. Can you elaborate what do you mean by default packages?

Comment: :I meant to say about classes which have no package defined comes in _default package_ isn't it?That's where I can't get how the access takes place for two individual classes that should be in the same package(_default_ package).

Comment: @justin If you don't mention any package in program then it considers its current directory to be its package. Suppose you created your programs on your desktop then its package would be considered to be desktop. So other classes that are present on desktop will be able to access it.

Comment: :Okay.Just consider a file containing two classes and is present in the desktop directory and no package is mentioned.So can  both classes access it's members even if it's not public?I would like to know which is given the priority:is it the **default package** access level or **members** access label while just considering two classes without any package.

Comment: @justin Yes they will be able to access each others' members unless they are made `private`. Default, protected and public all can be used in same package.

Comment: :Could you show me an example that has two classes in a single file and has no packages so it uses the default package(current directory) and accesses an member from another class.The reason why I'm asking this since as you stated in your answer since variables defined in methods are `local variables` and it's mandatory to place variable in a method in java is it possible to access an member from another class which is public?

Comment: @justin Check my update in the answer. I think it will solve your queries.

Comment: :That's a good answer.Could you tell me whether _package level access_ means accessing the members using an object of another class or without using an object of another class to access an member of another class(both classes are in the same package).Also could you change `First.a` to `a` because that's the case I would really like to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Default access modifier means we do not explicitly declare an access modifier for a class, field, 
method, etc.

A variable or method declared without any access control modifier is available to any other    
class    in the same package. The fields in an interface are implicitly public static final and 
the methods in an interface are by default public.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `class B`, `a` is not defined.

```
class B {
    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("Value of a is" + a );//cannot find `a` inside `B`
    }
}
```

Now coming to accessibility, since your both classes are in same package `B` class can access public, protected and default(no access modifiers) members of other class like `A`. But in your case `a` is a local variable inside the `A` member method `value()`, so `a` variable cannot be accessed outside the method where it was declared.

```
class A {
    public static void value() {
       int a;//not accessible outside this method
       a=5;
    }
    public static void main() {//FYI: this main is not valid to execute your code, missing here: `String[] args` argument
       value();
       //`a`, is even not accessible here, forget about class `B`
    }
}
```

Sample code, all are in same package:

```
class A {
   String bar;
}

class B {
  public foo() {
    A a = new A();//required, as `bar` is instance(non-static) member of class `A`
    a.bar 'hi there';//set value
    System.out.printf("a.bar = %s\n", a.bar);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Sample code with **nested class**:

```
class A {
  int foo;

  class B {
     void setFoo() {
       foo = 45; //accessing member of class `A`
     }
  }
}
```

Working code:

```html
<pre>
<code>
class A {
  private int foo;
  private B b;

  A() {
   foo = -1;
   b = new B();
  }

  class B {
     void setFoo(int foo) {
      System.out.printf("Inside B's setFoo(), foo = %d\n", foo);
        A.this.foo = foo; //accessing member of class `A`
     }
  }

  int getFoo() {
   return foo;
  }

  public void setFoo(int foo) {
   System.out.printf("Inside A's setFoo(), foo = %d\n", foo);
   b.setFoo(foo);
  }
}

class Ideone{
 public static void main (String[] args) {
  A a = new A();
  System.out.printf("main(), foo = %d\n", a.getFoo());
  a.setFoo(34);
  System.out.printf("main(), foo = %d\n", a.getFoo());
 }
}
</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: :I can understand your answer but could you show me a code in which `a` could be accessed without making `a` a local variable as you suggested and that too _without making an object_ of the class in which `a` resides.

Comment: :That's good but could you _remove the nested class_ and show me an example.

Comment: :But still I think you're using **constructors** which is a form of _object creation_ isn't it?Could you just show a simple example that means two classes and a variable `foo` is accessed from another class(either of two classes) _without using object creation_.I think we can do it using static modifier.Could you help me.